# How to check if array contain duplicate object value?

Tags: javascript

I need to find true of false if my array contain duplicate object value.

Suppose I have this array of objects

```
const array = [
    {
        id: "id1",
        quantity: 3,
        variation: "red",
        tax: 40
    },
    {
        id: "id1",
        quantity: 3,
        variation: "red",
        tax: 40
    },
    {
        id: "id2",
        quantity: 3,
        variation: "red",
        tax: 40
    }
]
```

Here I have to get true because here `id1` come twice in this array. If This array contain unique id everywhere then it should return false. How can I do that. I am not getting proper solution.

Comment: Does it have to be only id or any property? Every other property is identical.

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: "I am not getting proper solution." is not really a clear question though. What are you stuck on? Do you know how to check values in an array? If not, you could start with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```js
function checkDuplicates(arr) {
    let result = false;
    let ids = [];

    for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if(ids.includes(arr[x].id)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        } else {
            ids.push(arr[x].id);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(checkDuplicates(array))
```

Hope it helps.